# mock patch for the entire test session

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock, python-unittest.mock

***tl;dr*** how to have a `mock.patch` for a `@classmethod` last an entire test session instead of only within `with` scope or function scope?

I want to [mock patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) a class method. However, I would like to run `patch.object` once instead of once within every test.

Currently, I must call `patch.object` twice

```py
class MyClass():
    @classmethod
    def print_hello(cls):
        print("hello from the real MyClass.print_hello")

    def do_something(self):
        pass


def mock_print_hello(_cls):
    print("hello from the patched mock_print_hello")


class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_init(self):
        with mock.patch.object(MyClass, "print_hello", new_callable=mock_print_hello) as patch:
            MyClass.print_hello()
            MyClass()

    def test_do_something(self):
        with mock.patch.object(MyClass, "print_hello", new_callable=mock_print_hello) as patch:
            MyClass.print_hello()
            MyClass().do_something()
```

However, I would like to only call `patch.object` once:

```py
class MyClass():
    @classmethod
    def print_hello(cls) :
        print("hello from the real MyClass.print_hello")

    def do_something(self):
        pass


def mock_print_hello(_cls):
    print("hello from the patched mock_print_hello")


class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # this patch will not remain after setUpClass returns
        patch = mock.patch.object(MyClass, "print_hello", new_callable=mock_print_hello)

    def test_init(self):
        # this calls the real MyClass.print_hello, not mock_print_hello
        MyClass.print_hello()
        MyClass()

    def test_do_something(self):
        # this calls the real MyClass.print_hello, not mock_print_hello
        MyClass.print_hello()
        MyClass().do_something()
```

In practice, patching `MyClass.new` within `setUpClass` does not last beyond the scope of the function. In other words, the `test_init` and `test_do_something` do not call `mock_print_hello`, they call `MyClass.print_hello`.

How can I have the mock patch last beyond the scope of one function?

Answer (score 1):

In order to start patching, you have to either use a decorator or a context manager, or you can call [start](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) manually. Just calling `patch` or `patch.object` returns a patcher object, it does not start patching.

As you can't use the decorator or context manager in your setup code, you have to start/stop the patcher in the respective setUp/tearDown methods:

```py
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    patcher = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.patcher = mock.patch.object(MyClass, "print_hello", new_callable=mock_print_hello)
        cls.patcher.start()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.patcher.stop()
```

If you need the patching to persist in the whole module, you can do the same in the respective module functions:

```py
patcher = None

def setUpModule():
    global patcher
    patcher = mock.patch.object(...)
    patcher.start()

def tearDownModule():
    patcher.stop()
```

As an aside, if you were to use `pytest` instead of `unittest`, this could also be done using a context manager in a fixture:

```py
class MyClassTest:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup(self):
        with mock.patch.object(MyClass, "print_hello", new_callable=mock_print_hello):
            yield
```

or in the module case:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autosue=True)
def setup_module():
    with patch.object(...):
        yield
```